# Timer randomly resets when I clicked cancel

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is a timer. The button with the stopwatch symbol on it, is the Set button. I clicked it and entered 56 minutes and pressed start. I clicked the Set button again by accident, and when it prompted me, I clicked Cancel, and it just randomly reset back to 00:00. Why is this happening and how can I fix it? Did I do something wrong?

```js
class Timer {
  constructor(root) {
    root.innerHTML = Timer.getHTML();

    this.el = {
      minutes: root.querySelector(".timer__part--minutes"),
      seconds: root.querySelector(".timer__part--seconds"),
      control: root.querySelector(".timer__btn--control"),
      reset: root.querySelector(".timer__btn--reset")
    };

    this.interval = null;
    this.remainingSeconds = 0;

    this.el.control.addEventListener("click", () => {
      if (this.interval === null) {
        this.start();
      } else {
        this.stop();
      }
    });

    this.el.reset.addEventListener("click", () => {
      const inputMinutes = prompt("Enter number of minutes. To add seconds, use a decimal.");

      if (inputMinutes < 60) {
        this.stop();
        this.remainingSeconds = inputMinutes * 60;
        this.updateInterfaceTime();
      }
    });
  }

  updateInterfaceTime() {
    const minutes = Math.floor(this.remainingSeconds / 60);
    const seconds = this.remainingSeconds % 60;

    this.el.minutes.textContent = minutes.toString().padStart(2, "0");
    this.el.seconds.textContent = seconds.toString().padStart(2, "0");
  }

  updateInterfaceControls() {
    if (this.interval === null) {
      this.el.control.innerHTML = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="30px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="30px" fill="#ffffff"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none"/><path d="M8 5v14l11-7L8 5z"/></svg>`;
      this.el.control.classList.add("timer__btn--start");
      this.el.control.classList.remove("timer__btn--stop");
    } else {
      // Pause button
      this.el.control.innerHTML = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="30px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="30px" fill="#000000"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none"/><path d="M6 19h4V5H6v14zm8-14v14h4V5h-4z"/></svg>`;
      this.el.control.classList.add("timer__btn--stop");
      this.el.control.classList.remove("timer__btn--start");
    }
  }

  start() {
    if (this.remainingSeconds === 0) return;

    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.remainingSeconds--;
      this.updateInterfaceTime();

      if (this.remainingSeconds === 0) {
        this.stop();
      }
    }, 1000);

    this.updateInterfaceControls();
  }

  stop() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);

    this.interval = null;

    this.updateInterfaceControls();
  }

  static getHTML() {
    return `
            <span class="timer__part timer__part--minutes">00</span>
            <span class="timer__part">:</span>
            <span class="timer__part timer__part--seconds">00</span>
            <!-- Play button -->
<button type="button" class="timer__btn timer__btn--control timer__btn--start">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="30px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="30px" fill="#ffffff"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none"/><path d="M8 5v14l11-7L8 5z"/></svg>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="timer__btn timer__btn--reset" title="Click to add time. To add seconds, use a decimal.">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" height="30px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="30px" fill="#FFFFFF"><g><rect fill="none" height="24" width="24"/></g><g><g><g><path d="M15,1H9v2h6V1z M11,14h2V8h-2V14z M19.03,7.39l1.42-1.42c-0.43-0.51-0.9-0.99-1.41-1.41l-1.42,1.42 C16.07,4.74,14.12,4,12,4c-4.97,0-9,4.03-9,9s4.02,9,9,9s9-4.03,9-9C21,10.88,20.26,8.93,19.03,7.39z M12,20c-3.87,0-7-3.13-7-7 s3.13-7,7-7s7,3.13,7,7S15.87,20,12,20z"/></g></g></g></svg>
            </button>
        `;
    
  }
}

new Timer(
    document.querySelector(".timer")
);
```

```css
body {
  background: #dddddd;
  margin: 24px;
}

.timer {
  font-family: Roboto;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 24px 32px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background: white;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
}

.timer__part {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.timer__btn {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  background: #8208e6;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.timer__btn--start {
  background: #00b84c;
}

.timer__btn--stop {
  background: #ff0256;
}
```

```html
<div class="timer">
  <center>
    <div class="loader">
      <!-- The loading symbol will be shown until the timer loads. -->
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="40px" height="40px" viewBox="0 0 50 50" style="enable-background:new 0 0 50 50;" xml:space="preserve">
  <path fill="#000" d="M43.935,25.145c0-10.318-8.364-18.683-18.683-18.683c-10.318,0-18.683,8.365-18.683,18.683h4.068c0-8.071,6.543-14.615,14.615-14.615c8.072,0,14.615,6.543,14.615,14.615H43.935z">
    <animateTransform attributeType="xml"
      attributeName="transform"
      type="rotate"
      from="0 25 25"
      to="360 25 25"
      dur="0.6s"
      repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </path>
    </svg>
    </center>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

When you click `cancel` in `prompt` it will return `null` and in JS when you check `null < 60` it will `true` because when you compare `null` with number it will convert to `0` (you can check it just running `Number(null)` in console). The same result will be if you press `OK` with empty string because when you compare `''` with number it will convert to `0` (you can check it just running `Number('')` in console)

Your variable named `inputMinutes` can be `null`, `string`, and `empty string` (keep in mind that `string` with just spaces equal to `empty string` in your case, so you should use `trim()` to remove unnecessary spaces). When you compare `inputMinutes` with `60` in this line:

```js
if (inputMinutes < 60) {
    /*code*/
}
```

you can get 4 variants:

1. `null < 60`
2. `'' < 60`
3. `'string which can be convert to number' < 60`
4. `'string which can not be convert to number' < 60`

JS has it own rules how to compare different types. So I recommend you read these articles for full understand what and how JS compare:

You can read short version from [javascript.info](https://javascript.info)

- [Comparisons](https://javascript.info/comparison)

For full understanding you can read from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript):

- [Equality comparisons and sameness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness).
- [Less than operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Less_than)
- [Greater than operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Greater_than)
- [Less than or equal operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Less_than_or_equal)
- [Greater than or equal operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Greater_than_or_equal)
- [Equality operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality)
- [Inequality operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Inequality)
- [Strict equality operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality)
- [Strict inequality operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_inequality)

Let's continue :) As I said above when you compare something with number JS try to convert another type to `number`. So variants above will compared in this way (`Number(x)` will convert input to number type):

1. `Number(null) < 60`
2. `Number('') < 60`
3. `Number('string which can be convert to number') < 60`
4. `Number('string which can not be convert to number') < 60`

On next step:

1. `0 < 60` - this is `true`
2. `0 < 60` - this is `true`
3. `number < 60` - answer depends on number
4. `NaN < 60` - this is `false`

- In 3 variant we get simple number so it will work as you expected
- In 4 variant we get `NaN` so we get false so `if block` will not be executed

We are interested in the first 2 options. When we try to multiply something with number JS try to convert something to `number` with same rules so you get 2 variants:

1. `null * 60` => `0 * 60` - answer is `0`
2. `'' * 60` => `0 * 60` - answer is `0`

Because of this `this.remainingSeconds` will be equal to `0` so in `updateInterfaceTime` method `minutes` and `seconds` will be equal to `0` so you get `00:00` in your timer

Comment: It's not working

Comment: @ChristianSamu What is not working? Can you show me updated JS code where you check if `prompt` answer is not `null` and not an empty string?

Comment: @ChristianSamu I just tell you what is happening after your `promp` I didn't give a solution. I described a problem place in your code

Comment: nothing is working. it keeps resetting to 00:00

Comment: @ChristianSamu I will repeat for you again. I didn't post here a solution I just gave you explanation of problem, where is it and why does it happen. I think you can add by yourself some additional if statements if you understand what is the problem